# Primefaces dataExporter not exporting in pdf

Tags: java, pdf, xhtml, primefaces, data-export

Hi I like to export whole page in pdf like print, print is working but pdf not working,,

kinldy tell what iam wrong with

```
    <h:form>
               <h:commandLink>
                    <p:graphicImage value="/Images/pdf.png" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="export" fileName="test"/>                
                </h:commandLink>  
                <h:commandLink>  
                     <p:graphicImage value="/Images/print.png" />
                     <p:printer target="export" />  
                 </h:commandLink> 
                <h:panelGroup id="export">
_________________________
_________________________
_________________________
_________________________
_________________________
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

I getting error

```
  javax.servlet.ServletException: com/lowagie/text/Phrase
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/Phrase
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.Phrase
```

Thank you

Comment: It seems that you don't have iText jar in your classpath, Primefaces lists the dependencies on page 14 of 3.4 version user guide, Grab yourself a copy of iText jar from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/iText/)

Comment: Thanks @Sanjeevi.V, now its fine working in dataTable, how to proceed same thing to generate whole page in pdf, i getting error `javax.servlet.ServletException: Unsupported datasource target:"javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup", exporter must target a PrimeFaces DataTable.`

Comment: I think dataexport only used for dataTable, ok i will try to do mannually, if any one get solution for this means please update.. Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15046#p51409) answer for similar question at primefaces forum, You should probably look into iText library to create your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Sanjeevi.V, the whole page in xhtml format so i try to do conversiton [xhtml to pdf](http://www.dayon.nl/content/xhtml-pdf-java-0) i hope this is will help me to do mannualy,,, Thanks a lot once again...

Comment: @Sanjeevi.V please convert your comments to an answer.